# Flutter package Chewie: How to know video controller laid the first frame onto the screen without playing the video?

Tags: flutter, dart

Right now I have `autoInitialize: true`, `autoPlay: false` and `Chewie` shows the first frame of the video as expected however I don't like the transition since the first frame image pops out suddenly from a black screen.

So I wrapped `Chewie()` inside of an `AnimatedOpacity()` but I could not find a callback to set the `_opacity = 1.0` for a nice fade transition. I tried doing this with `_chewieController.videoPlayerController.value.initilized` inside of an `FutureBuilder` but nothing changed.

I guess `_chewieController.videoPlayerController.initialized` does NOT mean first frame is laid out on the screen. First frame image loads later on. How can I know when that happens?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```dart
_videoPlayerController.addListener(() {
  if (_videoPlayerController.value.initialized) {
    // do something here
  }
});
```